# Particle system not rendering in freestyle

Tags: particles, freestyle

I'm relatively new to blender so I'm sorry if the answer is obvious.

I've been trying to make a simple, non-photorealistic nature scene inside of Blender.

I would like to add a hand-drawn style outline around my grass. It works when I only select one group of grass, but when I make that into a particle system, it doesn't show up.

(I'm using Blender 2.8 and Eevee with freestyle rendering)

[image: This is how it looks like when the I set up a particle system using the grass][image: This is how it looks like when I use don't use a particle system]